# Can a refund be reversed?

Tags: refund, chargeback

Today I went to return a Christmas gift I bought myself because I realized it was a impulse buy and not something I would actually wear. I went to the Gucci store and gave the jacket to one of the store personnel. He inspected it and processed my refunded without any concerns or questions. I received a call about a hour later from the store saying that the jacket was dirty, and for me to go back to the store to get it, and that they will be doing a charge back. This is a $2,700 jacket that was checked completely by the store before I was able to return it. How it got dirty I dont know, and I doubt it was dirty when it was in my possession because I didn't even get a chance to wear it.

I was just wondering if it is even possible for my refund to be canceled after I have left the store. If the jacket was dirty like they say, it shouldn't have been accepted, and the refund should have been denied. Could I possibly be looking at my refund being charged back, or is that not even possible?

Comment: It seems someone at the store is trying to cover their a... bases. You should contact the store and dispute the claim that the item was sullied. It was checked when you turned it in, so it is not your problem. You should add the method of payment (seems like card to me) used.

Comment: Ouch $2700 for a jacket?!?!?!  What kind of income allows for such a purchase?

Comment: @PeteB. Income is irrelevant in this age of bountiful credit.

Answer (score 14):

Stores are not required to give refunds. They do it as a gesture of good will toward their customers, and can refuse any return for any reason.

That having been said, they did accept the jacket as a return. I'm assuming they gave you a "return receipt" that shows the item being returned and has a negative total. This is your proof that they accepted the item.

Here is what you can try:

First, do not go back to the store to pick up the jacket. In fact, it's best if you never go back to that store ever again. If they call you, tell them you returned the jacket and are not coming back to pick it up.

Next, I'm assuming that you paid with a credit card. Go online to your credit card's website and confirm that you see the original charge for the jacket, dated when you bought the jacket. You will hopefully also see the negative charge for the return in your "pending transactions."  If that is all you see, just wait for that pending transaction to become a cleared transaction, checking the website every day. Once it does, you'll know you got your refund.

If you wait a few days and the refund transaction never appears in the pending transactions, or never moves from pending to cleared, you could dispute the original charge with the credit card bank. Your return receipt is proof that you returned the item.

If you see the return transaction, but the store has put a new charge on your card, charging you for the jacket a second time, dispute that new charge as soon as it becomes a cleared transaction.

Good luck.

Comment: Stores are not required in general to give refunds, but if the store states that they give refunds, then they are required to do so.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, if a store has a written return policy, they have to follow it.  But watch out for the fine print, which can give the store any number of excuses to deny the return.